# jquery clone div change its id and and id of all children

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery 1.10.2 and trying to clone a div, which I have done successfully, but I also need to change the id's of that div and all of its children, which I am currently unsuccessful at.

I have search this and found several examples to help e.g [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331197/clone-a-div-and-change-the-ids-of-it-and-all-its-children-to-be-unique) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977041/changing-various-ids-after-cloning-in-jquery), but they havent worked for. I really cant see why. I know I must be doing something really obvious wrong. What is the reason for what i have done not to work? (I have l left my attempts in - but commented)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnSecondContact").click(function () {
    $("#divCustomerData").removeClass("col-lg-6 col-md-6");
    $("#divCustomerAddr").removeClass("col-lg-6 col-md-6");
    $("#divCustomerData").addClass("col-lg-4 col-md-4");
    $("#divCustomerAddr").addClass("col-lg-4 col-md-4");
    $('#divCustomerData').after(
        $('#divCustomerData').clone()
        //$('#divCustomerData').clone().attr("id", "newId").find("#divCustomerData").attr("id", "#divCustomerData_cloned")

        //$('#divCustomerData').clone(function () {
        //    $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "_cloned")
        //})
    )
    //$("#divCustomerData").clone(false).find("*[id]").andSelf().each(function () { $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "_cloned"); });
    $("#btnSecondContact").prop('disabled', true);
})
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `clone` too many times and lose your reference.

Change this

```
$('#divCustomerData').after(
        $('#divCustomerData').clone()
        //$('#divCustomerData').clone().attr("id", "newId").find("#divCustomerData").attr("id", "#divCustomerData_cloned")

        //$('#divCustomerData').clone(function () {
        //    $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "_cloned")
        //})
    )
```

To

```
var $clon = $('#divCustomerData').clone();
 $('#divCustomerData').after(
    $clon.attr("id", "newId").find("#divCustomerData").attr("id", "#divCustomerData_cloned")
)
```

Also notice that clone doesn't take a function :

So I don't know what you've tried to do in here :

```
//$('#divCustomerData').clone(function () {
        //    $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "_cloned")
        //})
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. But trying that does not work. however If I simply use $clon then I get the cloned elements, but obviously I still have the problem that ids are not changed