# Cloning a Div and changing the names and id of children to become unique

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys just a  quick question, I tried to replicate this: [Clone a div and change the ID's of it and all it's children to be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331197/clone-a-div-and-change-the-ids-of-it-and-all-its-children-to-be-unique)

Its exactly what I want and need but I can't seem to make it work.

This is what I got:

```
<div id="current_users">
    <table id="user_list">
        <tr id="user-0">
            <td id="first_name-0">Jane</td>
            <td id="last_name-0">Doe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="user-1">
            <td id="first_name-1">John</td>
            <td id="last_name-1">Doe</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<button id="button" onclick="duplicate()">Click me</button>

<script>
    function duplicate() {
        $("#current_users").clone(false).find("*[id]").andSelf().each(function () { $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "_cloned"); });
    }
  </script>
```

There are no errors showing up in my console, I tried looking for other solutions but this is the best I found. Thanks for those who can help

Comment: the `onlick` (missing c) probably isn't helping.

Comment: Sorry my mistake on the copy paste, it still does not work by the way :(

Comment: Also, for clarity, in case the above isn't just a snippet of more code: clone() creates a copy of an object in memory, it does not add it to the DOM.

Comment: Second click on `button` would create duplicate `id`s in `DOM` ?

Comment: Nodehead that is all my code, what do you suggest I put? I am not sure at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting `.addBack()` for `.andSelf()` using `$.now() * (index + 1)` within `.each()` to prevent duplicate `id`s in `DOM` , `.appendTo()`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="current_users">
  <table id="user_list">
    <tr id="user-0">
      <td id="first_name-0">Jane</td>
      <td id="last_name-0">Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="user-1">
      <td id="first_name-1">John</td>
      <td id="last_name-1">Doe</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<button id="button" onclick="duplicate()">Click me</button>

<script>
  function duplicate() {
    var clone = $("#current_users").clone(false);
    clone.find("*[id]").map(function(index, el) {
      el.id = el.id + "_cloned_" 
              + $.now() 
              * ( index + 1 );
      return el
    });
    clone.attr("id", function(index,id) {
      return id +"_cloned_"+ $("[id^=current_users]").length
    }).appendTo("body");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This works for me, I just need to change the appendTo and for the index. Actually I need to make it incremental but I think I can handle that. Thanks! Edit* Is there a way I can put appendTo it below the original div?

Comment: `random()`?!? Really??

Comment: @AlexisWilke _"`random()`?!? Really??"_ ? Not certain interpret correctly ?

Comment: Wouldn't the above code append cloned tr's / td's to the body rather than the cloned table? or am I missing something?

Comment: You cannot sensibly be thinking that `random()` is going to give you a unique identifier. If you have a problem because index starts at 0, then add 1: `$.now() * (index + 1)`.

Comment: @AlexisWilke _"cannot sensibly be thinking that random() is going to give you a unique identifier."_ See updated post. Adjusted to suggested `$.now() * (index + 1)` ; note, with only `$.now()` could return same timestamp for each element within current `.each()` iteration . `$.now() 
              * ( index === 0 ? Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)` would not return pseudo-random identifier ?

Comment: `random()` could return a value you are going to use again later... so if `random()` returns 0.001, you would get 1 twice.

Comment: @AlexisWilke `$.now()`: `new Date().getTime()` . `new Date().getTime() * Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)` could return duplicate ?

Answer (score 1):

you are showing your clone on body. Create a div like

```
<div id='cloned_output'></div>



function duplicate() {
    $("#current_users").clone(false).find("*[id]").andSelf().each(function () {

       $("#cloned_output").append( $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "_cloned"));

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There's likely a more elegant jQuery way of doing this (my jQuery's fairly poor), but here's a step-by-step way. Appending to body in this example, but can easily be changed to appended to another element. Also assuming you want the entire div cloned.

```
function duplicate(){

  // Clone
  $cloned_users = $('#current_users').clone();
  $cloned_users.attr('id', $cloned_users.attr('id') + '_cloned');

  // Change all internal ids
  $cloned_users.find('*[id]').each(function(){
    $elm = $(this);
    $elm.attr('id', $elm.attr('id') + '_cloned');
  });

  // Append to body
  $('body').append($cloned_users);

  // Or, after original div
  // $cloned_users.insertAfter($('#current_users'));

}
```